# Jquery slider fullscreen but with content underneath

Tags: jquery, image, slider, fullscreen

I am trying to find a slider like this one: http://www.adidas.dk/

If you look at the top slider, you can see it all ways fit screen but still you can scroll down - im very curious about where i can find this very cool plugin!

I will how ever need it so that there is 3 of these sliders beneath each other and with navigation it should scroll down to fit next slider on click.

I was hoping someone could either help me in the right direction, earlier have come across something like this and would share it with me or simply build it for me if you have the right skills.

Im not advanced in Jquery so its impossible for me to build myself - still learning :)

Hope some kind soul out there can be of assistence.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html][please open this link to find the full screen slider,There is code or method how to customize the effect in your page.]

Comment: Doesnt seems like its responsive? When i scale the screen the image doesnt follow? Also i need fullscreen like in the link from adidas.dk - did you see the slider in the link? Its the top one.